# How to copy a selection from word to excel using Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy word(s) from my word document to a specific cell in the excel workbook. I've used Bookmark to find the text i need and copy that then i open the workbook to paste to a specific cell - which is a vlookup reference.

My code runs but the pasting does not actually occur. I know the copy portion of the code works because when i run up until that point then manually paste the selection, it works just fine. I've tried multiple options of pasting but nothing has worked so far...

```
Selection. Paste

Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub copypastewordtoexcel()

Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Select
Selection.Copy

WorkbookToWorkOn = "C:\Users\arboari\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"

Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn)

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Select
Selection.Copy

For Each oSheet In oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
oSheet.Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValue)
Next oSheet

Set oRng = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i'd appreciate some guidance on this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should not need copy/paste: you can assign directly

```
Sub copypastewordtoexcel()

    Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
    Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String

    WorkbookToWorkOn = "C:\Users\arboari\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"

    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn)

    For Each oSheet In oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            oSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text
    Next oSheet

End Sub
```

EDIT: reading from a table cell

```
txt = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text
oSheet.Range("A1").Value = Left(txt, Len(txt)-2)
```

You need to strip off the two-character "end of cell" marker.

Comment: Yup. Much better.

Comment: Instead of using a bookmark, is it possible to assign it directly from a cell in a table in word? I tried the following but instead of just taking the text in there it adds a character at the end when i open the excel workbook.- e.g. Stewart •


`oSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text`